# What's the matter: Yiddish "was is der mehr?"

Tags: yiddish

We have in Yiddish an expression for "what's the matter" that sounds like "was is der mehr?". Is this German or what? I can't make sense of it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Admittedly I never heard this or any similar expression in German (not even unrelated to *"matter"*).

What comes to mind however is the now unusual German *"[die Mär](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/cgi-bin/WBNetz/wbgui_py?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GM01287)"* (used in the meaning of *tale, story, report*, derived from Old Hig German **mârî** and also in its diminutive still used in *"das Märchen"*).

By changing gender and thus article we could have said:

> **"Was ist die Mär?"** - *"What is the story?"* or *"What's up?"*

Nobody uses this expression nowadays but considering it's ancient roots in the German language it may well have survived in Yiddish.

Even at Grimm's times the usage of *"Mär*" was rare but it was used by [Heinrich Heine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heinrich_Heine) who wrote a poem to his friend [Meyerbeer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Giacomo_Meyerbeer):

> *Beeren-Meyer, Meyer-Beer!
>
>   Welch ein Lärm, **was ist die Mär**?
>
>   Willst Du wirklich jetzt gebären
>
>   Und den Heiland uns bescheren,
>
>   Der verheißen, der versprochen?*

Comment: Interestingly enough, Heinrich Heine was Jewish, as was Meyerbeer. Maybe he took this expression from Yiddish?